# QlikView How to group by attribute in other table

Tags: database, graph, aggregate-functions, qlikview, qliksense

Hello I currently have 2 tables like this:

Parcel which has idParcel,quantityParcel,idProduct

and

Product which has idProduct, nameProduct

When I try to execute `Aggr( sum(quantityParcel),[idProduct] )` it works just fine making the sum of quantityParcel by idProduct but when I try to run `Aggr( sum(quantityParcel),[nameProduct] )` it just returns the sum of all quantityParcel values without grouping anything, is there any way I can group by nameProduct referencing it from the Product table? The reason I want to do this is because I want to show the actual product name in my dimension instead of just the idProduct number, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `nameProduct` as Dimension why don't just use: `sum(quantityParcel)`

another option is to use `NODISTINCT` : `Aggr(NODISTINCT sum(quantityParcel),[nameProduct] )`